# Unable to install sharepoint 2010 in Windows 7

Tags: sharepoint, windows-7, sharepoint-2010

I am facing problem while installing **Sharepoint 2010 Server** on **Windows-7 Professional** I have followed the steps given in this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx). Still I am getting the following error while trying to run **Setup.exe**.

[image: Error Message]

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems that `SharePoint Server 2010` is only compatible with
>   `Windows Server 2008 x64`. But it's not. check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44210/Installing-SharePoint-Server-2010-on-Windows-7-x64).

Source: [Installing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 on Windows 7 x64](http://developmentsolutionsjunction.blogspot.in/2011/03/installing-microsoft-sharepoint-server.html)
It is much simple to do this. Just a little work and your SharePoint Installation ready to work on **Windows 7 64 bit Client OS**.

You can simply install SharePoint Server 2010 on your client OS just by modifying a config file.
Copy CD contents to a folder on your hard drive and Follow following steps:

1. Go to the Files folder
2. Go to the Setup folder
3. Open config.xml
4. Add the following line before the closing `</configuration>` tag

   `<Setting Id="AllowWindowsClientInstall" Value="True"/>`

Save the file and Run the Setup.exe. now it will work fine.

Remember: These lines are Case Sensitive so Write them correct.

On Windows 7, install the following additional prerequisites required before running Setup.exe:

`Microsoft FilterPack 2.0`. At a command prompt, type the following:
`installation directory folder\PrerequisiteInstallerFiles\FilterPack\FilterPack.msi`

1. [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=141237)
2. [SQL Server Native Client](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=123718)
3. [Windows Identity Foundation (Windows6.1-KB974405-x64.msu)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974405)
4. [Chart Controls](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=122517) (this is not required if you are going to install SharePoint Foundation 2010).
5. [SQL Server Analysis Services - ADOMD.Net](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/D/0/AD021EF1-9CBC-4D11-AB51-6A65019D4706/SQLSERVER2008_ASADOMD10.msi) (this is not required if you are going to install SharePoint Foundation 2010).

*For more detailed installation tutorial go through MSDN - [Setting Up the Development Environment for SharePoint 2010 on Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx)*

Comment: thanks, this [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44210/Installing-SharePoint-Server-2010-on-Windows-7-x64] helped me out to solve the issue.

Comment: Glad, it works for you.. i have done all of this by following the msdn articale.. my sharepoint was working fine..

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your copy of Sharepoint 2010 Server is intended to be installed onto a machine running Win Server 2008 SP2 or later. Not win 7. Either upgrade your machine or see if there's a more compatible copy of share point server.