# Can I install sharepoint foundation 2010 in Windows 7 Home Basic OS?

Tags: windows-7, sharepoint-2010

I have original Windows7 Homes Basic. Now I want to setup development environment for Sharepoint. But it will not able to install.

Can I install sharepoint foundation 2010 in Windows 7 Home Basic OS.
If we can please tell me the steps to follow.

Comment: What's a SharePoint developer doing using Windows 7 Home Basic?

Comment: I think it will not work on the Home edition. But if it is your first experience and you have at least Windows 7 Professional 64-bit, you can use SharePoint 2010 Easy Setup Script to install it in easy way: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23415

Answer (score 0):

> Can I install sharepoint foundation 2010 in Windows 7 Home Basic OS

**No**, you can not install sharepoint foundation 2010 in Windows 7 Home Basic. You will need at least Windows 7 Professional x64 to install SharePoint 2010.

*You can install it on your Windows 7/Vista x64 for Development purpose, but I guess it will only work on Professional or higher edition.*

Check [How to install IIS on windows 7 Home Basic edition?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproinstall/thread/f5f09f99-4a23-45b7-bc32-b5631d36b1e4) and [Windows 7 Home Basic - "Internet Information Services (IIS)](http://forums.iis.net/t/1163764.aspx) , Basic version does not have full functional IIS. then how we install Sharepoint on it. *With home basic, you don't have the IIS Manager.*

Reference:
[sharepoint server on windows 7 basic home](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/6fe41fc5-52ab-4382-9b70-93c0c2348c3d/)
[how to install SHarepoint 2010 Windows 7 Home Basic](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/cb0e2d0d-6eec-4d1f-b5f7-0bc9eebd2e8c/)

refer this to install Sharepoint on Win 7 -
[Unable to install sharepoint 2010 in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025716/unable-to-install-sharepoint-2010-in-windows-7/11026890#11026890)